# AWS elastic beanstalk cannot select network load balancer any more

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an application, and I'm trying to create an environment for that app. All the other configurations went through fine, but I cannot select the network load balancer. There is an error called "a is undefined" when the load balancer type is set to network. Application load balancer works fine, but I need the load balancer to work with TCP, so it has to be a network load balancer. How can I create an environment with network load balancer?

Here is the screenshot of the error, which is not very descriptive. All the other configs are kept default. I couldn't even go to any other pages without removing the network load balancer. Any help is appreciated.
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bug with the new console and the AWS team is working on it. You can use eb-cli to create a new environment with NLB.